# what makes these two pointer different?

Tags: c, pointers

I have a program in C

what I want to do is copy the `pApList` to `pApListCp`

```
ScanResult *pApListCp;
void ApListCallback(ScanResult *pApList)
{
    ap_num = pApList->ApNum;
    printf("ApListCallback,ap_num=%i\r\n",ap_num);
    for(i=0;i<ap_num;i++){
        char * ssidc = pApList->ApList[i].ssid;
        char temp[500] = "";
        strcpy(temp, ssidc);
        printf("ap cb,ssid=%s\r\n",temp);
        free(temp);
    }
    //memcpy(&hugebuf[sizeof(mxchip_cmd_head_t)-1], pApList->ApList, ap_num*sizeof(ApList_str));
    pApListCp=pApList;
    startScan = 0;
}
```

and I also print it twice.

```
case CMD_SCAN:

        printf("4 scan \r\n");
        mxchipStartScan();
        startScan = 1;

        while(startScan == 1){
          mxchipTick();
        }

        ap_num = pApListCp->ApNum;
        printf("\r\ncmd scan,ap_num=%i\r\n",ap_num);
        for(i=0;i<ap_num;i++){
            char * ssidc = pApListCp->ApList[i].ssid;
            char temp[500] = "";
            strcpy(temp, ssidc);
            printf("cmd scan,ssid=%s\r\n",temp);
            free(temp);
        }
        memcpy(p_reply->data, pApListCp->ApList, ap_num*sizeof(ApList_str));
            //memcpy((char * ) & p_reply->data[CONFIG_DATA_SIZE], pApListCp->ApList, ap_num*sizeof(ApList_str));

        p_reply->datalen = ap_num*sizeof(ApList_str);
        break;
```

but It seems difference in two results.

now the result looks like:

```
4 scan 
ApListCallback,ap_num=16
ap cb,ssid=Modim fashion
ap cb,ssid=timelessgz2
ap cb,ssid=
ap cb,ssid=timelessgz1
ap cb,ssid=sweet baby
ap cb,ssid=sweet baby 2
ap cb,ssid=JIMMY 3G
ap cb,ssid=ringierguest
ap cb,ssid=wudiuandiuan
ap cb,ssid=ChinaNet-GPi6
ap cb,ssid=Bert-Co
ap cb,ssid=TP-LINK_CBD04C
ap cb,ssid=ChinaNet-Ul6
ap cb,ssid=ZOC-TC5
ap cb,ssid=VAIO-VAIO_Network
ap cb,ssid=blue1

cmd scan,ap_num=16
cmd scan,ssid=屨 m fashion
cmd scan,ssid=timelessgz2
cmd scan,ssid=
cmd scan,ssid=timelessgz1
cmd scan,ssid=sweet baby
cmd scan,ssid=sweet baby 2
cmd scan,ssid=JIMMY 3G
cmd scan,ssid=ringierguest
cmd scan,ssid=wudiuandiuan
cmd scan,ssid=ChinaNet-GPi6
cmd scan,ssid=Bert-Co
cmd scan,ssid=TP-LINK_CBD04C
cmd scan,ssid=ChinaNet-Ul6
cmd scan,ssid=ZOC-TC5
cmd scan,ssid=VAIO-VAIO_Network
cmd scan,ssid=blue1
```

what makes the first item `Modim fashion` wrong??

Comment: Unicode/ASCII problems?

Comment: @Mints97 but there is no problem in other item string?

Comment: Provide [a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It is obvious from results that {ApList[0].ssid} is modified somewhere in between two prints,you have to only find that.

Comment: @Vagish but I can't see anywhere the `ApList ` is modified.. there is no any other place use this varible.

Comment: Please try to post an SSCCE, then it should be obvious: http://sscce.org/

Comment: @DavidGrayson I thought what I provide is enough.. becuz my program run in the chip. and I can't post all the program to here..

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be caused because of `free(temp);`.You have not allocated any memory here then why free?

`temp` being an local array will be stored in stack space and compiler reuse the stack after function exits.

Comment: Indeed a *free* on a wild pointer (actually address in this case) will likely cause UB.

Comment: I tried to delete those 2 for loop in the program... but got the same result.. so weired..

Comment: If you have deleted for loops then what you are printing?

Comment: I recieve the result from the android client.. and I can read the byte array there..